# Perform math operations inside static templated strings

Tags: javascript, string, templates

I have a nodejs app that takes in a json object with string templates inside it. Currently I am using the [string-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-template) package to fill in the templates:

```
{
  "template": "https://example.com/{value}/{index}",
}
```

The templates have a number of values available to them. Some will change some wont. I want to be able to do simple math operations on the values in the template like so:

```
{
  "template": "https://examplesite.com/{index * 2}
}
```

Safety is important here so I want to avoid adding any `eval` clauses to the templates. Is it possible to do simple math operations (`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`,`^`) in javascript strings in a safe manner?

Comment: What library are you using? Those aren't a built-in style of template strings

Comment: @ChristianScott, I edited the question (I am using [string-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-template))

Comment: AFAIK it's just a static thing--you'd need to pass in an object with values pre-computed: "A simple string template function based on named or indexed arguments". It doesn't execute code (again, AFAIK). You'll probably want a different templating engine if you want to execute code.

Comment: yes, same goes for what I know. My hope is that someone knows of a nice clean solution with another existing templating language. The best I could find on my own was [mustache-wax](http://jvitela.github.io/mustache-wax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem using [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

```
import Handlebars from 'handlebars'

Handlebars.registerHelper('+', (x, y) => x + y)
Handlebars.registerHelper('-', (x, y) => x - y)
Handlebars.registerHelper('*', (x, y) => x * y)
Handlebars.registerHelper('/', (x, y) => x / y)

const createTemplate = (templateStr) => {
  const template = Handlebars.compile(templateStr)
  return (data) => template(data)
}
```

here is how it is used

```
createTemplate("test {{'+' val 2}}")({ val: 13 }) // yields 15
```

This works exactly how I needed, and can even do nested math problems

```
createTemplate("test {{'*' ('+' val 2) 3}}")({ val: 13 }) // yields 45
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, it doesn't look like string-template supports expressions inside templates.

Let's say you wanted to double whatever value went into "index". You'd need to double that value when doing the formatting:

```
var foo = {
  "template": "https://examplesite.com/{index}"
}

format(foo.template, {
    index: index * 2
})
```

Another option might be using javascript's built in template strings, wrapped in a function:

```
function renderTemplate(index) {
  return `https://examplesite.com/${index * 2}`
}
```

You can put any expression inside these templates.

Comment: ES6 template literals are expanded immediately, you can't use them to generate output from dynamic data. You also can't read the template dynamically.

Comment: I need the logic to be pushed down to the templates, the app will consume different templates and some may have a need for math operations while others will not. As for built in template strings, the templates _need_ to be stored in json, so using javascript in them is not an option